# "Potrebbe esser stato mangiato" è voce del verbo mangiare?

Tags: verbs, grammar, auxiliary-verb, moods

In sostanza, sono in dubbio sul significato di "voce del verbo".

Su [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/voce/) leggo

> Sinon. più generico e com. del termine tecn. grammaticale forma, per indicare sia ogni diverso aspetto che assume nella flessione il verbo:

Allora cosa è la flessione? Sempre [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/flessione/) identifica *flessione verbale*  con *coniugazione dei verbi*.

Allora cosa è la coniugazione? Ancora [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/coniugazione/) dice che è

> il complesso delle forme che il verbo può assumere per esprimere il tempo, il modo, il numero, la persona e la diatesi.

Ora, l'esempio nel titolo esprime qualcosa di più che solo tempo, modo, numero, e persona che connotano l'"azione". In effetti, è facile individuare la persona (egli), il numero (singolare), e il modo (condizionale), ma già per il tempo, la questione è più complessa: la frase esprime un dubbio che esiste al tempo presente, in quanto non si sà se l'azione si è svolta già o meno nel passato. E la diatesi? Mi risulta difficile individuarla... *Potrebbe* mi sembra piuttosto attivo, ma *esser stato mangiato*? È... il participio passato passivo?¹ Penso di star dando i numeri, ma almeno dovrei aiutare a capire il mio dubbio.

---

(¹) D'altronde posso dire "La differenza tra *mangiare* ed *esser mangiato*", il che mi porta a pensare che *esser mangiato* si comporta come un infinito passivo, anche se io non ne ho mai sentito parlare.

Answer (score 3):

No. Le voci del verbo “mangiare” sono quelle che puoi trovare in qualunque prospetto della sua coniugazione, articolate secondo i vari *modi* (indicativo, congiuntivo etc.), molti dei quali hanno a loro volta dei *tempi* (presente, passato prossimo etc.). In più i verbi hanno anche una *diatesi*: attiva o passiva. Quella passiva in genere esiste solo per i verbi transitivi, come appunto “mangiare”.

Alcuni di questi tempi e diatesi si realizzano con i verbi ausiliari, i più usuali dei quali sono “essere” e “avere”. Per esempio il passato prossimo indicativo attivo è “io ho mangiato, tu hai mangiato...”, mentre lo stesso tempo e modo al passivo è “io sono stato mangiato, tu sei stato mangiato...”

Nel nostro caso, quindi:

- mangiare: infinito presente attivo
- aver mangiato: infinito passato attivo
- essere mangiato: infinito presente passivo
- essere stato mangiato: infinito passato passivo.

Quanto al verbo “potere” e ai suoi simili, come “volere” e “dovere”, in questo caso hanno la funzione di *verbi modali* (un tempo chiamati *servili*) e sono a loro volta un argomento molto ampio, che puoi approfondire [qui](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-modali_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/). Volendo li si può chiamare anch'essi ausiliari, ma comunque in genere sono considerati verbi a sé, che formano un'espressione unica con il verbo che reggono (che va sempre in qualche forma dell'infinito), ma che comunque rimane appunto composta da *due* verbi.

Comment: Ho studiato le coniugazioni; ho studiato i verbi modali (ho 33 anni e quando ero alle (mie) elementari li chiamavano ancora servili); non ricordo di aver sentito la parola "diàtesi" all'epoca; non ricordo che si sia dedicato troppo tempo ai modi indefiniti passivi; il punto è che no, nessuno mi ha dato una definizione di "voce del verbo". Tu hai mai letto in una grammatica "Dicesi voce del verbo..." seguita da una spiegazione esaustiva e inequivocabile? Io no, ma se tu ce l'hai, hai trovato la risposta che cerco :D

Comment: Ad ogni modo, per "potrebbe esser stato mangiato" c'è un appellativo meno generale di "espressione composta"? Certo "da due verbi" chiarisce, ma non mi sognerei di scrivere "Ecco una lista di espressioni composte da due verbi" in un capitolo che parla unicamente dei verbi. Allo stesso tempo "Ecco una lista di espressioni composte" seguita da "mangia, potrebbe mangiare, ha mangiato, potrebbe esser stato mangiato" mi sembrerebbe come "Ecco una lista di cose" seguita da "forchetta, coltello, cucchiaio, cucchiaino".

Comment: Quanto a “voce del verbo”, la definizione è quella del Treccani, ma in effetti allora il problema si sposta su che cosa fa parte della flessione del verbo, cioè la coniugazione, e per questo adotterei quello che dicono qui: https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/coniugazione-verbale_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano) : “Per coniugazione si intende l’insieme delle variazioni morfologiche del verbo in relazione al modo, al tempo, all’aspetto, alla diatesi, alla persona, al numero e al genere”.

Comment: L'*aspetto* è una delle caratteristiche di una voce verbale che in italiano non è molto esplicita: indica se l'azione è duratura (lavorava), compiuta (lavorò) etc. In altre lingue ha più importanza.

Comment: Infine, hai ragione: “espressione” è troppo vago. Qui, volendo usare un termine tecnico, direi “sintagma verbale”.